# how to set filetype after session restored with vim-session plugin

Tags: gvim, filetype, sessions

I used [exvim](https://exvim.github.io/) as session manager, it uses a project file with extension **.exvim**. The session is auto-loaded when double click the **.exvim**, and auto-saved on exit. But there're bugs and the dev is inactive for years, now I switch to use [vim-session](https://github.com/xolox/vim-session).

I like the '.exvim' idea, I'm trying to implement '.proj' with vim-session in my vimrc:

```
let g:session_autosave = 'yes' "auto saved
let g:session_autoload = 'no' "load by myself as below
function! s:open_proj_session()
    " if the buffer is /a/b/mars.proj, just get the 'mars'
    let session_name = fnamemodify(fnamemodify(bufname('%'), ":t"), ':r')
    " try to open it first
    call xolox#session#open_cmd(session_name, '', 'OpenSession') 

    " if it's not opened then it's not created, let's create it
    let cur_sess = xolox#session#find_current_session()
    if cur_sess != session_name
        call xolox#session#save_cmd(session_name, '', 'SaveSession')
    endif
endfunction
augroup MyProj
    autocmd!
    autocmd! BufRead,BufNewFile *.proj set filetype=proj "register .proj filetype
    autocmd FileType proj nested call s:open_proj_session()
augroup END
```

Once I open a **.proj** file, session loaded successfully, but buffers has no `filetype`, try to print filetype in some **.cpp** buffer with `:set filetype`, results in: `filetype=conf` or `filetype=`.  And the syntax highlight is not working.

I see the official dev is also inactive for years so I decide to post it here, how to fix this?

**Problem Update:**

Code updated, add a `nested` keyword works. Now only the active buffer not syntax highlighted. Its ``filetype=cpp` is already set, but has no syntax(*'No Syntax items defined for this buffer'*), all other buffer are syntax highlighted, why?

Comment: Have you tried to put the comment `"register .proj filetype` on another line to be sure that it doesn't mess with the autocommand? (Also I think `fnamemodify(fnamemodify(bufname('%'), ":t"), ':r')` could be `expand('%:t:r')`)

Comment: @statox The `expand('%:t:r')` is helpful, and it has the same result if I delete the comments

Comment: I think you might need the nested flag to your autocommands

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt The nested flag works, but still have some problem, the thread updated for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine:

```
Plug 'xolox/vim-session'
let g:session_autosave = 'yes' "auto saved
let g:session_autoload = 'no' "load by myself as below
function! s:open_proj_session()
    let sess_name = expand('%:t:r')

    let &titlestring = sess_name
    call xolox#session#open_cmd(sess_name, '', 'OpenSession') " open it first

    let cur_sess = xolox#session#find_current_session() " if it's not opened then it's not created, let's create it
    if cur_sess != sess_name
        call xolox#session#save_cmd(sess_name, '', 'SaveSession')
    endif

    " close the .proj buffer
    if bufnr(sess_name.'.proj') > 0
        exec 'bd '.sess_name.'.proj'
    endif

    "close the .vim buffer (session file)
    if bufnr(sess_name.'.vim') > 0
        exec 'bd '.sess_name.'.vim'
    endif
endfunction
augroup MyProj
    autocmd!
    autocmd! BufEnter *.proj nested call s:open_proj_session()
augroup END
set ssop+=resize,winpos,winsize,blank,folds
```